# The title command in a execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't use a `/title` command in a `/execute` command. Like this:

```
/execute @a[score_Health_min=0,score_Health_max=1] ~ ~ ~ /title @a title ["",{"text":"/!\\ You Died :( /!\\","color":"dark_red","underlined":true}]
```

I use this command and it won't work. Because I'm making a map and when the player died or dying, it will say in the screen:

> /!\ You Died /!\

Please help me I don't know how to do this and if it uses a fill clock. I'm just gonna add a fill clock in my map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` character is a special control character for escape sequences. You had placed it before a quotation mark, which essentially prevents that quote from doing its job (closing the string) and instead to be a part of the value. The result is the next available quote closing the string, which then leads to a syntax error due to the lack of a comma afterwards.

You will want to escape the backslash by applying another backslash before it.

As well, there is no `score_name_max` parameter, and is thus ignored. The parameter you want is simply `score_name`.

Fixed command:

```
/execute @a[score_Health_min=0,score_Health=1] ~ ~ ~ /title @a title ["",{"text":"/!\\ You Died :( /!\\","color":"dark_red","underlined":true}]
```

Comment: Good answer! In programming, the \ character deals with commands like these: `"Say "hi""` The computer would think the string is ended at the second `"`. That's why you use escape characters: `"Say \"hi\""`

Comment: Well it didn't worked for some reason and i'm using mc 1.9.2 so does it work?Because i'm making a minigame map and if a player dies,a title command appear but it does not.

Comment: @Rjlapatan I can't really help if you don't provide any error messages or details as to why it doesn't work "for some reason". The command itself does work as long as a player was found in the first place.

Comment: Its ok now if it doesn't work again,it means this question is now answered.Thanks for helping me @Skylinerw

Answer (score 1):

- where the spawn point is place two command blocks:

  /tp @p[r=2]

  /title @p[r=2]
- make these command blocks repeating (if you're on 1.9 just set it, on 1.8 you should create a clock or more simple a small Redstone circuit with repeaters in circle)

When a player die and is in the spawn location it will execute /title command only to him, and will be teleported to the real spawn location